# How long can a transceiver be unused before I have to use a variac?

Tags: transceiver, equipment-operation, maintenance

I have an old TenTec Argosy II that hasn’t been powered up for 20 years.

How long can electronics go unpowered before I have to worry about the electrolytic needed a slow power up with a Variac?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92660/discussion-on-question-by-kd4ttc-how-long-can-a-transceiver-be-unused-before-i-h).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Consider writing an answer instead of leaving many comments.

Comment: Please post comments [into this answer's chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92660/discussion-on-question-by-kd4ttc-how-long-can-a-transceiver-be-unused-before-i-h) and not here. Please read the [commenting guidelines](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) as to what should and should not be posted in comments.

Comment: I'm looking, but I don't see a chat area.  The presence of a chat area is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no set time period. Play it safe, bring it up slowly and be done with it.

You can also put a ~100w incandescent lamp in series with the AC line (or better yet, a clamp-on AC current meter) as you bring up the voltage. If the capacitors are not bad, then the lamp should dim as the capacitors charge.

Comment: The Argosy manual calls for a separate, external power supply. Are there electrolytics internal to the radio that could be a problem? OTOH, there appears to be numerous slug-tuned coils ... could require alignment!

Comment: I thought I'd power up the power supply first unloaded to spare the transceiver.

Comment: @kd4ttc Great idea. :-) Also, I've added some information about reforming capacitors in [this question's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92660/discussion-on-question-by-kd4ttc-how-long-can-a-transceiver-be-unused-before-i-h).